# What effective indicators can be used to measure the degree of reconciliation in a post-conflict society?

Tags: peace-treaty

What effective indicators can be used to measure the degree of reconciliation in a post-conflict society?

For instance, Rwanda is perceived as a success story whereas Bosnia is not necessarily seen as a society in which reconciliation has been hugely successful. What is this based on?

Comment: Who makes this contrast/assessment between Rwanda and Bosnia?

Comment: For purposes of what? For making foreign investments? For determining eligibility for foreign aid? To trigger some domestic provision of a peace treaty like ending civil disabilities for former officials who were stripped of those rights temporarily? To restore civilian rule or lead to the departure of peace keepers? Or just for purposes of discussion by political scientists? The reason you want to know influences the appropriate answer.